# Browsers not responding

Tags: windows-7, internet, troubleshooting, windows-live-mail, chromium

A strange thing started to happen to my computer yesterday, and I can not recall installing anything new or updating anything the last few days either.
It was first the browser, Chromium, that started to freeze up and not respond for ages, say 10 minutes. Then my email, Windows Live Mail client started doing the same thing, I click on an email and the program goes "not responding" for 5-10 minutes.

At first I thought it was Chromium, so i reinstalled it but no help, So i installed Opera and thought I would give it t a try, but not same thing is happening to Opera so it is clearly an OS issue or/and internet connection issue.

Does anyone know what the problem can be?

Im running Windows 7 32bit on a dual core Sony Vaio laptop with 4gb ram. There is nothing wrong with the actual internet connection as it works fine on other computers on the network, and the connection it self does not drop.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running current AV software?  Have you done a scan?

Are there any errors or other events in the event log related to Chrome or LiveMail?

Comment: I have run both ESET and Microsoft Security Essentials and nothing found. Thanks for pointing out the log file, I have gone through the events for the last 5 hours and there are a lot of errors. Traced it down to it might have been the service UPnP Host Device that was disabled. Now how/who/why it was disabled... I do not know.

Comment: no its still doing it, not sure what to do :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes i got the same problem as well. Ran through av check and no result. Then i ran spy bot search and destroy and deleted some cookies that they think is suspucicous. then defrag my whole laptop and reboot it. Since then everything went back to normal.